# pandas.Series.apply() lambda function to count data-frame column values with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, count, series

This post follows on from another one I posted which can be found here:
[use groupby() and for loop to count column values with conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75342368/use-groupby-and-for-loop-to-count-column-values-with-conditions)

I am working with the same data again:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta

random.seed(365)

#some data
start_date = pd.date_range(start = "2015-01-09", end = "2022-09-11", freq = "6D")
end_date = [start_date + timedelta(days = np.random.exponential(scale = 100)) for start_date in start_date]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"start_date":start_date,
    "end_date":end_date}
)
#randomly remove some end dates
df["end_date"] = df["end_date"].sample(frac = 0.7).reset_index(drop = True)
df["end_date"] = df["end_date"].dt.date.astype("datetime64[ns]")
```

Like in the previous post, I first created a `pd.Series` with the 1st day of every month in the entire history of the data

```
dates = pd.Series(df["start_date"].dt.to_period("M").sort_values(ascending = True).unique()).dt.start_time
```

What I now want to do is count the number of rows in the data-frame where the `df["start_date"]` values are *less than the 1st day of each month in the series* **and where the** `df["end_date"]` **values are greater than the 1st day of each month in the series**

I would think that I would apply a `lambda` function or use `np.logical_and` on the `dates` series to obtain the output I am after - the logic of which would look something like this:

```
#only obtain those rows with end dates
inactives = df[df["end_date"].isnull() == False]

dates.apply(
    lambda x: (inactives[inactives["start_date"] < x] & inactives[inactives["cancel_date"] > x]).count()
)
```

or like this:

```
dates.apply(
    lambda x: np.logical_and(
        inactives[inactives["start_date"] < x,
        inactives[inactives["cancel_date"] > x]]
    ).sum())
```

The resulting output would look like this:

| month_first | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2015-01-01 | 10 |
| 2015-02-01 | 25 |
| 2015-03-01 | 45 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, we can use apply lambda for this. So, first, we create our list of first days in each month. Here we use `freq` `"MS"` to create start of month inside our defined interval.

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({"month_first": pd.date_range(start="2015-01-01", end="2022-10-01", freq = "MS")})
```

This will result in this table:

```
   month_first
0   2015-01-01
1   2015-02-01
2   2015-03-01
3   2015-04-01
4   2015-05-01
..         ...
89  2022-06-01
90  2022-07-01
91  2022-08-01
92  2022-09-01
93  2022-10-01

[94 rows x 1 columns]
```

Then we apply the lambda function below. So for each of the rows in our date range, we take from `inactives` which the `start_date` is less and `end_date` is greater. We use `&` operator to perform `and` operation to each row of our resulting comparisons. Then, we use `sum` to sum all the boolean values.

```
new_df["count"] = new_df["month_first"].apply(
    lambda x: ((inactives["start_date"] < x) & (inactives["end_date"] > x)).sum())
```

This will result in this table:

```
   month_first  count
0   2015-01-01      0
1   2015-02-01      4
2   2015-03-01      9
3   2015-04-01     14
4   2015-05-01     19
..         ...    ...
89  2022-06-01     25
90  2022-07-01     22
91  2022-08-01     19
92  2022-09-01     13
93  2022-10-01     13

[94 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you so much your way worked, thoroughly appreciate it